# Is it possible to migrate vb6 application running on windows server 2003 to windows server 2012

Tags: windows, migration, vb6-migration

we have an application running on windows server 2003 which needs to be migrated to windows sever 2012. Is it possible to do the as is migration without actually updating the application. The application is currently scheduled in windows scheduler on windows server 2003. Also please suggest if we can achieve this with any migration tool.

Comment: One would expect a VB6 executable to run fine on Windows 2012, copy it and any of its dependencies over and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

VB6 applications should generally work without changes in all current Windows versions, including Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10. The official word at [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, and Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) is:

> The Visual Basic team is committed to “It Just Works” compatibility for Visual Basic 6.0 applications on the following supported Windows operating systems: Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 including R2, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 including R2, and Windows 10.

Now, you mention that this particular app `is currently scheduled in windows scheduler`. There have been significant changes between Server 2003 (or Win XP) and 2012 (or Win 8.x) in areas of security, file/registry virtualization, UAC etc. If your app violates any of the new rules, then it may require an update - but that would be because of what it *does*, and *not* because it's written in VB6.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed several .exe created in vb6 in Windows Server 2012 R2 without problem.
The only question was the use of an very old setup.exe for installing, that was replaced to using an setup.msi, but the .exe and .dll and even .ocx incuded in the solution all works.